# How does F# know that bitArray elements are bool while enumerating in seq builder?

Tags: f#

```
    seq{
        for bit in BitArray(10) do 
        yield bit
    }
```

`bit` is of `bool` type. I checked with ILSpy and there's an explicit cast added in one of closures generated.

`BitArray` implements only plain (not generic) `IEnumerable`. How does F# know that it's a `bool`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[According to the F# 4.1 specification's ***Section 6.5.6 Sequence Iteration Expressions***](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf), F# does casting even for a non-generic `IEnumerable` if the `IEnumerable` has an `Item` property with a non-`object` type (highlighting mine):

> An expression of the following form is a sequence iteration
>   expression:
>
> *for* ***pat*** *in* ***expr1*** *do* ***expr2*** *done*
>
> The type of ***pat*** is the same as the return type of the ***Current*** property on the enumerator value. However,
>   if the ***Current*** property has return type ***obj*** and the collection type ***ty***
>   has an ***Item*** property with a more specific (non-object) return type
>   ***ty2***, type ***ty2*** is used instead, and a dynamic cast is inserted to
>   convert ***v.Current*** to ***ty2***.

[If we look at the source code for `BitArray`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/bitarray.cs,179), we see that it does indeed have an `Item` property with type `bool`:

```
public bool this[int index] {
        get {
            return Get(index);
        }
        set {
            Set(index,value);
        }
}
```

Thus, F# will explicitly cast to `bool` while iterating.

Comment: That was my guess but I couldn't find it in the spec. Thanks for finding it.